# ContentPresenter triggers not working

Tags: wpf, controltemplate, contentpresenter

I have a ContentPresenter inside a ControlTemplate trying to layout a TabItem. I want the foreground color of the TextBlock inside the header to change color when the tab is selected. My template is the following:

```
<TabControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TabPanel">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="TabControl">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,0"></Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="TabItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                                         VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                         HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                         ContentSource="Header"
                                         Margin="30,10,30,10"/>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="DarkGoldenrod"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>    
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="Black"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>    
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</TabControl.Resources>
```

Unfortunately the triggers are doing nothing. Several other posts here on SO show a `Setter` tag that looks exactly like mine, using `TargetName` to make sure we only change the header and not the whole tab. The property is recognized and compiles, but nothing happens.

What the heck is going on, and what am I doing wrong? This has been driving me nuts for hours!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it!

I had the header like this:

```
<TabItem.Header>
    <TextBlock>My Header</TextBlock>
</TabItem.Header>
```

Problem was, there's *already* a TextBlock inside the header, you don't need to wrap the text again.

```
<TabItem.Header>
    My Header
</TabItem.Header>
```

And it works.

Answer (score 1):

Works exactly as expected for me, your problem may be lying somewhere else...